# Is GetByteCount(string) additive?

Tags: c#-4.0, character-encoding

Specifically, if

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(stringA) + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(stringB) = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(stringA + stringB).
```

is always true. (some quick tests indicate so, but I'm not sure if its true in all cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. The number of bytes it takes to store `stringA + stringB` is the same as the number of bytes needed for `stringA`, plus the bytes needed for `stringB`. This is because strings are not null-terminated in .NET.

If they would have been null-terminated, then the number of bytes it takes to store `stringA + stringB` would be one byte less than the bytes needed for `stringA` + the bytes needed for `stringB`, since there's one null-terminator per string, so in the first case you combine the strings first, removing the null-terminator of the first string, whereas in the second example, you add the two null bytes as well.